# How to become active directly an open app?

Tags: xfce, desktop-environments

I'm wondering how do you switch the open apps..

what do you usually use to go directly to an app? are you using any shortcuts? are you placing the apps in different desktops and go to them using Ctrl+Fnumber? or are you still using alt-tab :)?

I'm using ubuntu 12.04 and xfce.

Answer (score 0):

To switch between the all Open Application we all use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> hotkey.That will do the Job.

Comment: thanks, but im looking for a way to active directly an open app, a shortcut i mean..

Comment: could you explain more about what exactly you want?